# django fcgi - call a management command with subprocess.Popen

Tags: nginx, django, fcgi

I'm using an app called django-chronograph. It has a code of line which works in my dev environment and does not work in production:

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', get_manage_py(), 'run_job', str(self.pk)])

This line crashes in production with: unknown command run_job
Whereas when I run directly from command line: manage.py run_job
It works fine.

Interestingly it worked once when we exchanged 'python' with 'usr/bin/python'. 
then we restarted the server once more and it was back to old behaviour.

Thus it seems as we have a python path issue. 
I'm not the guy who is running the server, its my app that should run and it would be great to get some help here. Attention: I'm a total noob regarding server-administration..

server environment:
NGINX with FCGI-Daemon 
FCGI in prefork-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, uh... [don't do that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

```
django.core.management.call_command('run_job', str(self.pk))
```

Comment: Ok that s a good hint. I will replace it and I guess this will overcome my problem.

Just for curiousity, why do you think subprocess.Popen should be absolutely not used ? Maybe then I should tell the author of django-chronograph..

Comment: Because there's already a perfectly good mechanism for invoking commands from within the app itself.

Comment: -1 call_command is blocking; Popen is not